# PHP IMAP update the draft using the ID

Tags: php, email, imap

I am working on my PHP to creating the draft email to save on the server. I have got a problem with update the draft because on my code it will only allow me to create and save the draft without update it. The only thing that the draft can be updated is use the ID. At the moment I am using `imap_mail_compose` to creating the draft but they wont allow me to update the draft with the ID.

Example: imap_mail_compose($envelope, $body_cont, $id);

Here is the code:

```
$envelope["to"]  = $email_receipt;
$envelope["subject"]  = $email_subject;
$envelope['date'] = date('D,j M Y H:i');
$envelope['from'] = $username;
$part["type"] = TYPETEXT;
$part["subtype"] = "plain";
$part["description"] = "part description";
$part["contents.data"] = $email_message;
$body_cont[1] = $part;
$msg = imap_mail_compose($envelope, $body_cont);
```

I have also tried this:

```
$mailbox = imap_open($mailserver, $username, $password);

imap_append($mailbox, $mailserver,
    "From: ".$from."r\n".
    "To: ".$to."\r\n".
    "Subject: ".$subject."\r\n".
    "Date: ".date("r", strtotime("now"))."\r\n".
    "Message-ID: ".$messageID."\r\n".
    "MIME-Version: 1 \r\n".
    "Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=\"$boundary1\"\r\n".
    "\r\n\r\n".
    "--$boundary1\r\n".
    "Content-Type: multipart/alternative; boundary=\"$boundary2\"\r\n".
    "\r\n\r\n".
    // ADD Plain text data
    "--$boundary2\r\n".
    "Content-Type: text/plain; charset=\"utf-8\"\r\n".
    "Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable\r\n".
    "\r\n\r\n".
    $draft_message."\r\n".
    "\r\n\r\n".
    // ADD Html content
    "--$boundary2\r\n".
    "Content-Type: text/html; charset=\"utf-8\"\r\n".
    "Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable \r\n".
    "\r\n\r\n".
    html_entity_decode($sent_message)."\r\n".
    "\r\n\r\n".
    "--$boundary1\r\n".
    "\r\n\r\n".
    // ADD attachment(s)
    $attachment1.
    "\r\n\r\n".
    "--$boundary1--\r\n\r\n",
    "\\Seen"
);
```

However, it still wont let me to update the draft using with the id as it will only creating and nothing is else. I cant think of a way how I can update the draft using the ID.

Do you know I could update the draft using `imap_append` or `imap_mail_compose` with the ID?

Thank you.

Comment: I guess that the only option is delete the draft and create the new draft. What do you think?

Comment: IMAP has immutable messages.  You cannot update the text of a message.  You must delete the old message, and replace it with a new one.

Comment: @Max oh thank you for your advice so I got it now.

Comment: Or, more reliably, upload the new one and delete the old one upon success. That way in case of failure you end up with bonus data rather than zero data.